# Microsoft Dynamics Nav Connector For Java

Tags: java, authentication, microsoft-dynamics-nav

Currently I am working on implementing a connector for Microsoft Dynamics Nav in Java.

For that I want to create a connection with Dynamics Nav server through NTLM. Most of the blogs and documentations I found regarding this are outdated.

[Connecting to NAV Web Services from Java](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/freddyk/2010/01/19/connecting-to-nav-web-services-from-java/)

It will be appreciated if anyone can suggest me a method to handle Dynamics Nav authentication using `org.apache.http.client.HttpClient`. (Please suggest me if there is any Java client library available for Dynamics Nav)

Furthermore, it will be appreciated if any one can suggest me a place where I can get a free Dynamics Nav testing environment to test my Dynamics Nav connector application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows **Challenge/Response** (`NTLM`) is the authentication protocol used on networks that include systems running the Windows operating system and on stand-alone systems. I was able to handle `NTLM` authentication using `org.apache.http.client.HttpClient` version `4.4`.

Here is the Maven dependency I have used (Methods and method names can be slightly different in other versions).

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
 <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
 <version>4.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Following imports are required for the implementation. This is the basic requirement for a non-SSL connection.

```
import org.apache.http.auth.AuthScope;
import org.apache.http.auth.NTCredentials;
import org.apache.http.client.CredentialsProvider;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicCredentialsProvider;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder;
```

Here is the implementation. Need to replace `Username`, `Password`, and `Domain` with real credentials.

```
CredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create()
                .setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider)
                .build();

credentialsProvider.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, new NTCredentials("Username", "Password", null, "Domain"));
```

Now this http client can be used to communicate with the Dynamics NAV API.

But I was unable to find a free testing environment for Microsoft Dynamics NAV within my region (Asia). But few cloud service providers are offering free testing trials for other regions.

As a Linux user I had to install Windows in a virtual environment and install Dynamics NAV on it to create a testing environment. If you are familiar with Docker you can download the Dynamics NAV Docker image from [this link](https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/dynamics-nav/).